# Open Popup window contain Post value from form

Tags: forms, popup, window

I Have this HTML form

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
      <select name="CARS" id="Exam">
          <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
          <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
          <option value="FORD">FORD</option>
     </select>
      <input name="CarID" type="hidden" id="CarID" value="<?php echo $_POST['CarID']; ?>" />
      <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Button" onclick="open_exam()" />
</form>
```

I want when I submit this form open "Formpage.php" in popup wendiow with fixed size contain POST valus of CARS and CarID

Answer (score 0):

The link below might help you. It describes two ways of submitting values in a popup window:

http://dtbaker.net/web-development/submit-a-form-into-a-popup/